# How to use my Web class library from a windows project

Tags: asp.net, windows

I have a Web project in which I defined some methods to parse some webpages. I then save the retrieved data in a DB.
Now I have run a lengthy operation(it may take 2 days) in which I continously parse webpage this way.

Can I use the webproject from a Windows project. If I try to add a refference to it it doesn't work. How should I do it?

I have used until now an asp.net application, and done the calls to the parsing methods in the pageLoad event but after an hour or so the process stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the best design: Shared assemblies should not have a UI implementation. I suggest you split the assemblies you wish to call from your windows app from your web app into a separate assembly. Your web and windows apps should be in separate solutions, referencing your now separate assembly project.

Comment: This program is only for me. So I don't want to change anything. You are right, that I should split those, but I don't have the time. Can I do it somway else?

Comment: I can't think of much off-hand. Can't you run your web solution on one port and then make requests to it from the windows project?

Comment: I'm going to implement a webservice exposing those methods and add the windows prj as a client

Comment: That would work and webservices are quicker to set up than Wcf